# dual Os and partitioning

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 10.10, windows-7

I have a 150 gig hard drive with Ubuntu 12.10 currently installed what I want to do is format the hard disk and make three separate partitions. A 30 gig partition for windows  7, a 4 gig partition for ubuntu 10.10 and the rest for my files. My concern was how to do this and if it were possible ? and will I be able to access my files when I booted either os

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to  dual boot system with windows 7 and ubuntu. There are many posts and guides that can help you with it. Refer any of them.
Your partitioning scheme looks ok, but i would recommend you dedicate atleast 6gb of space for your ubuntu installation and first do a clean install of windows 7 and then go for ubuntu installation. It would be easier that way.
As far as accessing your files from either os, Ubuntu has inbuild support for NTFS but for windows you will need some third party softwares/drivers to access your ext4 partitions(which ubuntu uses as default filesystem).